# How to return a number from an array from a specific x and y location?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am making a super mario game and the map for it is made from an array. like so

```
    const map = 
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,];
```

In order to make collisions i want to find the index of the block that is under mario, and check whether its 0 or something else, which would allow me to make him stop falling when a block with the index 1 is under him.

I am trying to write it like this:

```
export function findBlockUnder(posX: number, posY: number) {
  for (let index = 0; index < map.length; index++) {
  return map[index] }
}
```

But this returns the first index of the array.
Is there a way to get the index from the position Y of mario?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have defined the `width` and `height` of your map :

```
function findBlockUnder(posX: number, posY: number) {
  return map[posY * width + posX]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the entries in the array represent left to right, top to bottom, and you know how many columns there are in the map, you can look up a given position via:

```js
const GRID_COLUMNS = 32; // or whatever

function findBlockUnder(x, y) {
  return map[ y * GRID_COLUMNS + x ]
}
```

However, if you broke your map into a two-dimensional array such that each entry represented a row of cell values, you could then access a given cell via `rows[y][x]`. (It might be more intuitive if it were chunked into columns instead of rows so the x would come first, but for the purposes of this discussion this is fine.)

The snippet below demonstrates this idea, rendering the map onto a canvas and then highlighting a cell at random and displaying its coordinates and value. Most of the code here is to support the drawing and highlighting but it seemed useful to have a visualization.

```js
const map = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
];


// splits the input array into arrays of the given length
function chunk(data, size, prev = []) {
  prev.push(data.splice(0, size));
  return data.length ? chunk(data, size, prev) : prev;
}

const numCols = 32;

// break map into an array rows, 32 cells per row
// so we can access a row via rows[y], and a specific
// cell via rows[y][x]
const rows = chunk(map, numCols);

// random cell highlighting interval
const rate = 2000;

// container for text output
const outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');

// get the canvas and its drawing context
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// compute cell size based on canvas size
// and the number of rows and columns
const cellSize = {
  width: ctx.canvas.width / numCols,
  height: ctx.canvas.height / rows.length
}

// define some colors
const colors = ['bisque', 'tomato'];

// gap between cells
const inset = 1;

// initial paint of the cells
rows.forEach((columns, r) => {
  columns.forEach((value, c) => {
    drawCell(c, r);
  });
})

// utility for filling the cell at x, y.
// if color isn't unspecified it'll use the map's value to get a color
function drawCell(x, y, color) {
  ctx.fillStyle = color || colors[rows[y][x] % colors.length];
  ctx.fillRect(x * cellSize.width + inset, y * cellSize.height + inset, cellSize.width - inset, cellSize.height - inset);
}

// chooses a cell at random and highlights it
function highlightRandomCell() {
  // choose a random coordinate
  const x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (numCols - 1));
  const y = Math.floor(Math.random() * rows.length);

  // get the cell's value
  const cellValue = rows[y][x];

  // display the coordinate and its value in the output div
  outputDiv.innerHTML = `(${x}, ${y}) ${cellValue}`;

  // fill the cell
  drawCell(x, y, 'black');

  // reset the cell
  setTimeout(() => drawCell(x, y), rate);
}

// highlight some cells
setInterval(highlightRandomCell, rate);
```

```html
<canvas width="200" height="112"></canvas>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work for me, in function findBlockUnder(x, y)  are the x and y supposed to be marios coordinates? And in the end what does it return? does it return a simple number 1 or 0? because when i implement this it breaks the whole game :(

Comment: What do the numbers in your map array represent?

Comment: they are just number which i later use to draw images like
if (map[index] == 1) {
      context.drawImage(siena,
        x * size - mapOffsetX,
        y * size - mapOffsetY,
        size,
        size);
    }

    

    if (map[index] == 2) {
      context.drawImage(question,
        x * size - mapOffsetX,
        y * size - mapOffsetY,
        size,
        size);
    }